# All involutive isometry has a fix point

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ an isometry. Then $T(x)=Mx+v$ for some orthogonal matrix $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and some vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$. We suppose $T$ involutive, that mean that $T^2=id$. I have to prove that $T$ has a fix point.

*Attempts*

So, if $c=-(M-I)^{-1}v$, then $$T(c)=c.$$
Indeed,

$$T(c)=-M(M-I)^{-1}v+v=-(M-I)(M-I)^{-1}v+v-(M-I)^{-1}v=-(M-I)^{-1}v=c.$$

But this only hold whenever $(M-I)^{-1}$ invertible. Since $M$ is orthogonal, it may be not the case that $M-I$ is invertible. So, how can I do ? Since I didn't use the fact that $T$ is involutive whenever $M-I$ is invertible, I suppose that we need this assumption here. But I don't know how I can use it. The only thing I see it's that since $T$ is involutive, $$M^2x+Mv+v=x.$$
But this doesn't really help. Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 1):

If $M-I$ not invertible, there is $u\neq 0$ s.t. $(M-I)u=0$. Since $T$ is involutive (and as you remarked),
\begin{align*}
M^2x+Mv+v=x&\iff (M^2-I)x+Mv+v=0\\
&\iff (M+I)(M-I)x+Mv+v=0.\tag{E}
\end{align*}

In particular, evaluating $(E)$ for $x=u$ yields $Mv=-v$. Therefore, $c=\frac{1}{2}v$ is a fixed point.

Comment: Thank a lot Mr. Surb. It's indeed easier than what I thought. Shall I deduce that if and isometry is not involutive and $M-I$ invertible, then $T$ has always a fix point ?

Comment: Yes, and you provided a proof for that :-)